# Status is a duplicate error. I’m trying to make my bot post a tweet, but it’s not working. (Python)

Tags: python, twitter, twitterapi-python

```
import tweepy

CONSUMER_KEY = 'My key'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'My secret'
ACCESS_KEY = 'my key'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'my secret'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

try:
    api.verify_credentials()
    print("Authentication OK")
except:
    print("Error during authentication")

api.update_status("Hello")
```

Obviously at the top I don’t actually have my secret, my key, etc. up there, but I have the actual keys and it connects just fine. The problem is I keep getting an error whenever I try to send the tweet hello. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error traceback, as that contains valuable information about the problem

Comment: Fix what? You haven't told what the actual problem is, which is why I asked for clarification

Comment: The error message is that it says “Status is a duplicate.”

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch such exception.
I bet that the api throws DuplicateError (or similar as you don't show the stacktrace) when the status you set is identical.

something like:

```
from contextlib import suppress
from <your api module> import DuplicateError
...
with suppress(DuplicateError):
    api.update_status("Hello")
...
```